# Selecting all values above a threshold and then a random sample of the values below the threshold

Tags: r

Using the `cars` dataset for example (shown below), I want to create a new data.frame by selecting all of the rows where cars$speed >= 12 and a random sample of 5 from the rows where cars$speed < 12.

```
> head(cars)
  speed dist
1     4    2
2     4   10
3     7    4
4     7   22
5     8   16
6     9   10
```

I can do this in multiple steps by first selecting the rows where `speed` >= 12 using

```
one <- cars[cars$speed >=12 , ]
```

then select a random sample of 5 where cars$speed < 12

```
two <- cars[sample( which( cars$speed < 12) , 5 ) , ]
```

and then `rbind()` the two data.frames.

However, I want to add the code to a larger loop and a single step with the same outcome would be greatly preferred.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you still need to rbind the results but you can do it in one line of code. I've used the sample_n function from dplyr for the sampling:

```
library(dplyr)

rbind(sample_n(cars[cars$speed<12,], 5), cars[cars$speed>=12,])
```

dplyr also has the `rbind_list` function if you need something faster than `rbind`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how much more this can be condensed, but here's one approach:

```
library(data.table)
cdt <- data.table(cars)
set.seed(1)
##
rbind(
  cdt[speed>11,],
  cdt[speed<12,][sample(1:.N,5),])
```

and just to show that the 5 rows were correctly sampled,

```
R> rbind(
    cdt[speed>11,],
    cdt[speed<12,][sample(1:.N,5),]
    )[order(speed)][1:8,]
   speed dist
1:     4    2
2:     7   22
3:     7    4
4:     8   16
5:    10   18
6:    12   14
7:    12   20
8:    12   24
```

This isn't necessarily a `data.table` specific approach, I just find the syntax convenient to use. Also, if your actual data is very large, you might see a performance benefit from using a `data.table` and replacing `rbind(<first subset>, <second subset>)` with `rbindlist(list(<first subset>,<second subset>))`.

**Edit**:
Thanks to @Arun, another `data.table` approach:

```
cdt[
  ,if (grp) .SD else .SD[sample(.N, 5L)],
  .(grp=speed>11), 
  .SDcols=1:2]
```

Comment: @Arun Thank you! `data.table` provides an unusually rich syntax for a single package, so it's always nice to learn some more of its grammar. I wasn't aware that you could define inline groups like that.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a less elegant solution, but one that just uses plain vanilla R:

```
cars[c(which(cars$speed >=12),sample(which(cars$speed < 12) , 5 )) ,]
```

This might not speed things up but it avoids the additional call of `rbind`.